# ImageMagick: Is there an equivalent of Gimp's tool to "shrink" and "grow" a selection?

Tags: imagemagick, mask, gimp, shrink

I have a black and white mask [image](http://st.depositphotos.com/1064024/545/i/450/depositphotos_5451352-Meat-collection.jpg) produced with this **ImageMagick** command:

```
convert in.jpg -threshold 85% out.png
```

Giving me this result:

[image]

I'd like to reduce the size of each piece like if I was doing it with **Gimp** by selecting the white background, inverting the selection and *shrink* it by X pixels.

Is it possible to do it with **ImageMagick** and if yes, how ?

Comment: Sure, use `-morphology dilate disk:3` or similar to dilate the white.

Comment: Imagemagick `-morphology dilate disk:3` will shrink the black while `-morphology erode disk:3` will enlarge the black. Or you can use `open` and `close` to do both. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can use -morphology close to reduce the white holes in the black. But if you use too large a kernel size, it will start to merge the black regions together.

```
convert image.png -morphology open octagon:4 result.png
```

[image]

Here you can see with size 4, it has removed all but one white hole, but has started to connect two of the black areas.