# ImageMagick: Filling big holes

Tags: imagemagick, mask

How to fill big holes in black and white images with **ImageMagick**, like in the element at row 6, column 1 ?

[image]

=== ADDED ===

Actually, I need to fill inner holes and bays in a mask like the one below. With Gimp, I would *fuzzy select* the background, *invert* the selection, *grow* it by 20 pixels, *shrink* it by 20 pixels and then *Edit > Fill with Foreground color*.

[image]

Comment: Please show your GIMP result so we know exactly what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very similar to your other recent post [ImageMagick: Is there an equivalent of Gimp's tool to "shrink" and "grow" a selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312877/imagemagick-is-there-an-equivalent-of-gimps-tool-to-shrink-and-grow-a-sele).

For small holes, -morphology will work. But if your holes are larger than the distance between black regions, the black regions will merge.

The best way to do that is to use Imagemagick connected components. This will not bleed between regions. But if your holes are larger than any black regions, those black regions will be merged into white if above the area-threshold.

```
convert image.png \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=500 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, it almost fixed my problem. I just updated my question to go a bit further.